# How do I periodically crawl a REST API using RxJs?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm using RxJs's IntervalObservable to poll a REST API every second for new sensor data. The REST API responds with "buckets" of sensor measurements made during 10 seconds, so a response from the API may also contain a HTTP header 'next' that is pointing to a more recent bucket of sensor data, if that is available.

My current implementation (see below) has 2 problems:

- The sensor data fetching starts from a timestamp in the past, which can mean fetching a lot of data buckets. If a user navigates away from the Angular component that uses this service, it destroys the service, but the initial data fetching just continues. I feel like I should keep track of the Observable returned by getSensorObservations() inside the updateVisualization() method and unsubscribe to that on destroying the service, but this would mean that, whenever I start calling the updateVisualization() with the IntervalObservable, I will have "an observable in an (interval) observable" and I'll need to kill both. I think this is not the best way to do it.
- The initial updateVisualization() can take some time to fetch all necessary historical data, however the next updateVisualization() calls are started anyway with the IntervalObservable, without waiting for the initial call.

Do you have some advice for these mixed observables?

```
export class WidgetService {
  private widget: Widget;
  private visualizer: any;
  private updateScheduler: Subscription;
  private timestampOfMostRecentObservation?: number;

  constructor(private sensorGateway: SensorGatewayCommunicationService) { }

  public initializeVisualization() {
    this.visualizer = new TimeSeriesLineChartWithTimeRangeSelector();
    this.visualizer.draw(`widget-${this.widget.id}-visualization`, this.widget.name, this.widget.seriesName);
    // First update of the visualization with sensor data since a timestamp in the past (121 seconds ago here):
    const initialFromTimestamp = Date.now() - 121 * 1000;
    this.updateVisualization(initialFromTimestamp);
    // Next updates of the visualization are scheduled every second:
    this.updateScheduler = IntervalObservable.create(1000)
      .subscribe(() => this.updateVisualization(this.timestampOfMostRecentObservation));
  }

  public destroy() {
    this.updateScheduler.unsubscribe();
    this.visualizer.destroy();
  }

  private updateVisualization(fromTimestamp: number) {
    const urlForNewObservations = this.widget.sensorMeasurementsUrl + `?from=${fromTimestamp.toString()}`;
    this.getSensorObservations(urlForNewObservations)
      .pipe(
        expand(({sensorObservations, nextUrl}) => { // https://ncjamieson.com/understanding-expand/
          if (sensorObservations && sensorObservations.length > 0 && nextUrl) {
            return this.getSensorObservations(nextUrl);
          } else {
            return empty();
          }
        }),
        concatMap(({sensorObservations}) => sensorObservations),
      )
      .subscribe((sensorObservations: [number, number][]) => {
        const downsampledObservations = this.downsampleSensorObservations(sensorObservations);
        this.visualizer.update(downsampledObservations);
      });
  }

  private getSensorObservations(urlForNewObservations: string): Observable<{
    sensorObservations: object[],
    nextUrl: string | null
  }> {
    return this.sensorGateway.getApiResource(urlForNewObservations).pipe(
      map(response => {
        if ('values' in response.body) {
          return {
            sensorObservations: response.body['values'].map(observation => [
              observation[0],
              observation[1]
            ]),
            nextUrl: this.getNextLinkUrl(response)
          };
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      })
    );
  }

  private getNextLinkUrl(response: HttpResponse<object>): string | null {
    if (response.headers.has('link')) {
      const linkHeader = response.headers.get('link');
      /* Example of a linkHeader:
       *'</sensors/1/properties/1/observations/20180711/12/19?from=1531311594456>; rel="self",
       * </sensors/1/properties/1/observations/20180711/12/18>; rel="prev",
       * </sensors/1/properties/1/observations/20180711/12/20>; rel="next"' */
      const links = linkHeader.split(',');
      const nextLink = links.find(link => link.endsWith('; rel="next"'));
      if (nextLink) {
        return nextLink.substring(nextLink.indexOf('<') + 1, nextLink.indexOf('>'));
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: TLDR; 2) You can initially call service to get historical thata and then `switchMap` to interval observable. This way interval will kick in after initial data fetching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the subscription of one observable to trigger another, I would flip the problem on its head and create a single observable which does what you want.

I would propose something like this in your initialise method:

```
let fromTimestamp = Date.now() - 121 * 1000;
// Create a base observable, doesn't really matter what it is
this.subscription = of(true).pipe(
    // Map to the right call fur the current time
    flatMap(() => {
        const urlForNewObservations = this.widget.sensorMeasurementsUrl + `?from=${fromTimestamp.toString()}`;
        return this.getSensorObservations(urlForNewObservations);
    }),

    // Repeat the REST call while the sensor returns a next URL:
    expand(({sensorObservations, nextUrl}) => { // https://ncjamieson.com/understanding-expand/

      if (sensorObservations && sensorObservations.length > 0 && nextUrl) {
        // Set the fromTimestamp for the next set of observations.
        fromTimestamp = this.parseTimestamp(nextUrl, fromTimestamp);
        return this.getSensorObservations(nextUrl);
      } else {
        return empty();
      }
    }),
    concatMap(({sensorObservations}) => sensorObservations),

    // Keep repeating this
    repeat(),
    
    // But wait a second between each one
    delay(1000),        

    // Terminate the whole thing when the service is destroyed / stopped.              
    takeWhile(() => !this.destroyed)  
).subscribe((sensorObservations: [number, number][]) => {
    const downsampledObservations = this.downsampleSensorObservations(sensorObservations);
    this.visualizer.update(downsampledObservations);
});
```

You'll need to implement parseTimestamp to parse the relevant next timestamp from the URL or similar.

Then implement ngOnDestroy to set this.destroyed to true and do `if (this.subscription) this.subscription.unsubscribe();`, which will kill the subscription when the service is destroyed - and manually set it to true/unsubscribe in your destroy method if you want to manually control that also.

Comment: Thank you! This way of managing the API calls solves both problems mentioned in the question.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it @SanderVandenHautte - I find that with Observables, the right answer is almost always "try and create a single observable that does the right thing".

Comment: I notice that my answer isn't setting "fromTimestamp" correctly, I trust you've been able to fix that?

Comment: Yes, I've set he URL and fromTimestamp (using this.timestampOfMostRecentObservation) inside the flatMap(). However, I cried victory too soon, my first test was with a fromTimestamp that returned an empty sensor data bucket. Putting the fromTimestamp a little earlier results in a lot of consecutive calls to the same URL (and same fromTimestamp). I set the this.timestampOfMostRecentObservation in a pipe with tap() inside the getSensorObservations() method, immediately after the HTTP call there. Why is this timestamp variable not adapted each time?

Comment: I've just updated the answer - I don't see in our original code where you were setting this.timestampOfMostRecentObservation so I've had to guess how you'd do that, but take a look and see if that works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176342/discussion-between-sander-vanden-hautte-and-mark-hughes).

Comment: Updated answer to include unsubscription from observable to try and ensure the repeat() is cancelled correctly, as discussed in chat. Please try this and let me know.

Comment: Note that according to the docs @SanderVandenHautte `@Injectable` are scoped to the lifetime of the application https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injectable-ngmodule-or-component so it would be expected that the service would not be destroyed when the component is destroyed.

Comment: Yes, I have noticed. The injected service was living as a singleton in the application, so I moved the logic in the service back to the component. Then the destroy worked as expected.

Comment: Cool - at least in terms of managing the lifetime correctly, that sounds like a good choice. If something is closely tied to the lifetime of a display concern like a component, it's usually a good choice to put that code in the component in question, and putting long-lived (or side-effect/state free re-usable code) in services.